# chrome.runtime.connectNative generates Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I did write an chrome extension that calls this connect() function to connect to a local C++ program:

```
function connect() {
  console.log("test1");
  //port = chrome.extension.connectNative('com.a.chrome_interface');
  port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.a.chrome_interface');

  port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
  console.log("test5");
}
```

I can see the test1 in the Console, but afterwards I got the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

in the line

```
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.a.chrome_interface');
```

My extensions manifest file is here:

```
{
  "name": "CPP_Connect",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Send data to CPP program",

  "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "js": ["contentscript.js"]
   }
  ],

  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs", "nativeMessaging", "<all_urls>"],

  "manifest_version": 2

}
```

My com.a.chrome_interface.json looks like this:

```
{
"name": "com.a.chrome_interface",
"description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
"path": "com.a.chrome_interface",
"type": "stdio",
"allowed_origins": [
"chrome-extension://abc.../"
]
}
```

and com.a.chrome_interface is a linux executable C++ file that generates a file, if it is called and this file is never created. 
I did put both files in

```
 /etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts/
```

So I guess, I did register my C++ correctly but I also guess, if I would register it wrong, I should get a different error.
If I use chrome.extension.connect() the script runs trough and the error message disapear but no data arrive in my C++ program.

I did read and try to follow instructions on 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging
and googled a lot but I could find out the reason of my problem.

I'm using Chromium 34 on Ubuntu 12.04.

1. As I'm writing an extension, do I have to use chrome.runtime.connectNative() or chrome.extension.connectNative()?
2. How can I connect and send data to my C++ program?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback for that error?

Comment: Is that what you are asking for? `test1 contentscript.js:17
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function contentscript.js:19
connect contentscript.js:19`

Comment: Now I did find out that `connectNative()` is not available in a content script. But I just have this content script. Now I have to find out how to send data out of a content script.

Comment: @EmbeddedDesign You should post that as an answer ("my problem was that it's unavailable from a content script"). As for sending data out, you need regular Messaging and a background page that acts like a proxy for your data.

Comment: @Xan: Thanks for your feedback. Now I did. Is there a reason why you did not write your answer as an answer?

Comment: @EmbeddedDesign You figured it out yourself; you deserve the reputation from the self-answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`connectNative()` is not available in a content scripts. 
To connect to a local program the content script must send the data e.g. to the background script of the extension and in the background script, 
`port = chrome.extension.connectNative`
can be used.
So here a solution:

contentscript.js:

```
....
// send data to background script
chrome.extension.sendRequest("Some Data");
....
```

background.js:

```
function connect() {
    // connect to local program com.a.chrome_interface
    port = chrome.extension.connectNative('com.a.chrome_interface');
    port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
}

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(data, sender) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        connect();
        sendNativeMessage(data);
    }
});
```

manifest.json as above in my question but additionaly:

```
...
  "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
...
```

`com.a.chrome_interface.json` is unchange as in the question above.

Comment: Doesn't work. Using your code where `chrome.extension.connectNative` is in the background script, the error still shows  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMB9s.png

Comment: Do not forget "permissions": [
        "nativeMessaging"
    ],"