# Native Messaging API error: Specified native messaging host not found

Tags: objective-c, macos, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I'm developing an objective-c app for OS X that will involve message passing with Google Chrome.  I have followed the examples and downloaded the samples from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).  However, I cannot get the extension to connect to my app.  The path to my app in the manifest file is the absolute path to a unix-executable file found at "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app_name-UUID/Build/Products/Debug/app_name.app/Contents/MacOS/app_name".  I have placed the same manifest file in both the locations noted in the previous link (although I understand only one is required).

When I try to connect to the running app I get the message "Failed to connect: Specified native messaging host not found".

Can I test the messaging API while the native app is still in development? If so, how? Or do I need to package the app into a .dmg file first?

Comment: Start Chrome from the terminal and look at the output in the terminal to see more helpful error messages.

Comment: That didn't show me any additional output.

Comment: Does the following answer solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25193936?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, on Mac.  RobW helped me through an earlier issue, but now I get "Specified native messaging host not found".  I've gone over and over the directions for this specific error here (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-location) to no avail.  Everything looks right, but no sooner do I connect than an onDisconnect is fired with that message as the chrome.runtime.lastError.message.

Answer (score -1):

See RobW's answer here: [Native Messaging Host Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726799/chrome-native-messaging-why-am-i-receiving-a-specified-native-messaging-host). The solution may be that you have your "NativeMessagingHosts" folder (which contains the manifest) inside a folder named "Default".  Just move the NativeMessagingHosts folder up one level so that it resides in the "Chrome" folder. The documentation was not yet updated.