# Chrome extension - open new tab when browser opened in background (Mac)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

## Used

Chrome 37.0.2062.120, Chrome Extension. MacBook Pro, MacOS 10.9.3.

Permissions granted, new tabs are being opened normally.

I use Chrome Notifications and if user clicks the specific button in the notification, new tab is opened.

## Problem

When Chrome is "hidden" (not closed completely, but kinda works in background, when you click red bubble with a cross in the left top corner of Mac Chrome), opening new tab is not triggering browser to "restore" (open).

***Thus, browser remains hidden and no tab is opened (visibly not opened, technically the callback is invoked).***

## Code

Opening from background.js

```
// if user triggers new tab open from Chrome Notification
chrome.tabs.create({url:someUrl})
```

## Editions

**Edition 1**. Tabs are just visibly not opened, technically the callback is invoked

**Edition 2**. The code below is better as it focuses the opened window if it is not focused at the moment of tab creation. However, does not solve the original problem.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:someUrl}, function(tab){
  chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {focused: true})
})
```

**Edition 3**. Here we go, it throws an error in background:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.create: No current window
```

## Solution

Many thanks to Xan.

```
function new_tab(url){
  // trying to create a tab
  chrome.tabs.create({url:url}, function(tab){
    if(!tab) {
      // probably no window available
      chrome.windows.create({url:url},function(win){
        // better to focus after window creation callback
        chrome.windows.update(win.id, {focused: true}) 
      })
    } else {
      // better to focus after tab creation callback
      chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {focused: true})
    }
  })
}
```

Of course this function needs to be modified if you need to pass extra options or callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the window focused:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:someUrl}, function(tab){
  chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {focused: true});
});
```

---

In a case that there is no active window, you need to account for that and create one if required:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:someUrl}, function(tab){
  if(!tab) {
    // Probably, there was no active window
    chrome.windows.create({url:someUrl, focused:true});
  } else {
    chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {focused: true});
  }
});
```

Note that this will probably not respect the default window state (maximized/normal), but better than nothing. I tested it on an extension with `"background"` permission.

Comment: Me neither, but I know that it's not going to work for I have already experienced the issue that the OP reported ;)

Comment: So, is this state of Chrome the same as all visible windows closed, like a `background`-enabled extension?

Comment: No, the issue is different. The question of the OP is slightly inaccurate; the tabs *are* opened, but they are not visible.

Comment: No. I'll elaborate in an answer, then you'll see why.

Comment: See my answer. If you're currently running a Windows VM, could you follow the steps from the bug report and see if it also occurs on Windows? If so, then I will add the Os-Windows label to the bug report.

Comment: @RobW Cannot reproduce on Win7 with 37.0.2062.120 m (64-bit)

Comment: Seems specific to Linux and Mac then.

Comment: I added edition #1 regarding to "visibly" and "technically" opened tab.

Comment: @igorpavlov Have you already tried Xan's answer? I *assumed* that his instructions does not work because it doesn't work on Linux, but I have to admit that I haven't tried it on a Mac yet.

Comment: This code actually is useful for me, solves another problem: when window is opened, but not focused and I trigger the tab from notification. However, if Chrome is working in background, neither Chrome window, nor the tab is opened.

Comment: I assume then, again, that the condition is "no windows open, extension running in `background` mode". Please try to run `chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win){console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError); console.log(win);})` while this happens. It's possible that you have to open a window first.

Comment: Updated the post, please see Edition 3.

Comment: Fixed my answer. Caveats apply, but it works. You need such special measures if you expect to keep running in background.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer only applies to Linux and Mac (not to Windows where the bug in question does not exist).*

A Chrome extension cannot focus a window unless at least a part of Chrome is the currently active window. I reported this bug a month ago with a detailed steps-to-reproduce as [Issue 407817: chrome.windows.create({ focused:true }) within a desktop notification does not create a focused window](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=407817).

Unfortunately, there is nothing that you can do in an extension. If it's a personal extension, you could create a [native messaging host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) and write a native application that puts the focus on the new window (if it is not a personal extension, then you have to ask your users to also install that native messaging host).

Comment: It is my personal extension. Could you explain how can I use "native messaging host" to solve my issue?

Comment: @igorpavlov Read the linked documentation to learn more about the native messaging protocol, then write a program (C, Python, Bash, AppleScript (?), whatever you want) that puts focus on the window. [Here is an example of a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24777120/938089) that uses the native message protocol. On Linux, I could use `xdotool` or `wmctrl` to change the window focus. Use your Google skills to find something similar for Mac. [Here are step-by-step instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25193936) to install a native messaging host on a Mac.