# Native messaging - Failed to connect: Specified native messaging host not found

Tags: chrome-native-messaging

I am new to native messaging. I am trying to start my calculator app from google extension. I downloaded an example from [google's document](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging). The example works fine. It starts some python based host app. When I change the path in the host's json file, I am getting an error :

> "Failed to connect: Specified native messaging host not found."

This is my native's hosts manifest json

```
{
 "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo",
 "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
 "path": "/Users/anand-4379/Applications/Calculator.app“,
 "type": "stdio",
 "allowed_origins": [
"chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
]
}
```

Initially, I was having trouble running the example I downloaded from the documentation. It worked after I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385991/chrome-extension-nativemessaging-connectnative-undefined/25193936#25193936).