# Chrome nativeMessaging example fails on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I downloaded the official Chrome [nativeMessaging example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging) to test it out.

To do this, I installed the app from chrome://extensions, by choosing Load Unpacked. No problems so far.

I then installed the host. I'm using Windows 7, so I ran install_host.bat, which claimed that "The operation completed successfully." However, when I go to chrome://apps/ and click the Connect button, I get this error:

```
Failed to connect: Native host has exited.
```

Is there some reason this would happen? Restarting Chrome did not fix the issue, nor did uninstalling and then reinstalling the host program.

(I noticed that native-messaging-example-host.bat requires Python 2, so I modified it to run Python 2 explicitly. If I run native-messaging-example-host.bat from the command line, it pops up a little example program of its own with a GUI and seems to work correctly.)

Comment: I can confirm that the following registry entry was created:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.example.echo.
Its value points to the ...\host\com.google.chrome.example.echo-win.json file from the downloaded example.

Comment: Make sure `python.exe` is in PATH or edit native-messaging-example-host.bat to point to the correct executable. For example I've used `py -2` instead.

Comment: It is in the path. I also tried using an absolute path directly to the Python 2 executable.

Comment: Since it works for me, the example is probably correct. Try looking for answers/articles on how to debug nativeMessaging like --enable-logging and so on.

Comment: You don't need to run the host manually in the background, right? When you click Connect, the app should start the host automatically, right?

Comment: Yes, it should start automatically. Another debugging idea: add `msg %SESSIONNAME% foo` to the batch file so you know it starts at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using a non-standard character in the path leading to the host executable. This wouldn't be a problem for any other program, but Chrome's native messaging API doesn't like it, I guess.

By the way, the documentation on setting up this example is near-nonexistent, but this stack overflow link has some useful info: [Chrome Extension NativeMessaging 'connectNative' undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385991/chrome-extension-nativemessaging-connectnative-undefined/25193936#25193936)